# How to tell if GIF is animated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, rmagick, animated-gif

I have this Rails app with Paperclip for image uploads -- but how do I check if the image is an animated GIF with RMagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the `scenes` associated with the image.  In `Rmagick` that means doing something like this:

```
image = Magick::ImageList.new(image_file)

if image.scene == 0
  #this is not an animated gif
else
  #this is an animated gif
end
```

Comment: probably you mean `image = `