# How can I convert a .gif image to .jpeg if the given .gif image is not a animated gif?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm using Ruby on Rails and the `paper-clip` Gem and I would like to to convert a `.gif` image to `.jpeg` if the `.gif` image is not a animated `gif`.

This is my code:

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: Proc.new { |file| file.instance.check_image_gif? ? {
        :'960' => ["960>x960", :gif],
        :'640' => ["640>x640", :gif],
        :'320' => ["320>x320", :gif]
      }:{
       :'960' => ["960>x960", :jpg],
       :'640' => ["640>x640", :jpg],
       :'320' => ["320>x320", :jpg]
      }
     }
    def check_image_gif?
      # I want to check animation gif here. 
      image.instance.image_content_type =~ %r(gif) ? true : false
    end
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238816/how-to-tell-if-gif-is-animated

Comment: thanks, but I can't understand to send data from paperclip to rmagick...

Comment: Paperclip already uses ImageMagick, so maybe you could just try: `Magick::ImageList.new(image.url).scenes > 0` in your `check_image_gif?`

Comment: Maybe I use Proc.new, so I can't get image's url...

Comment: I think I can get animation gif or not after post process, but I must do before make thumbnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved by myself.

```
def check_image_gif?
  begin
    file = image.instance.image.queued_for_write[:original]
    img = Magick::Image.read(file.path)
    animation = (img.size>1)
    unless animation
      image.instance.image_content_type = "image/jpeg"
    end
  rescue => e
  end
  image.instance.image_content_type =~ %r(gif) ? true : false
end
```

I added `rmagick` Gem.